# regex to restrict a range of numbers and Alpha in xslt

Tags: regex, xslt

I have the following numbers Range T30000000 and T89999999
That is all the numbers that fall withing the range of 30000000 and 89999999 The T is the prefix.. 
Any Idea how I might use regex to filter the values in xslt?
Thanks

Comment: [range regex generator](https://github.com/dimka665/range-regex)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following regex

```
T[3-8]\d{7}
```

Comment: My thought as well, here's a demo link https://regex101.com/r/LyCkIf/1.